# NSTextAttachment not working on WatchOS 2?

Tags: ios, uikit, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos

I have a WatchKit extension project I'm migrating over to WatchOS 2.0, and for some reason after the migration, I'm getting a compiler error stating that NSTextAttachment is an unknown type. I'm not sure if this is a bug with Xcode 7 or not. It was working fine in Xcode 6 and WatchOS 1. It's only everything referring to NSTextAttachment that's giving me this issue. Is it not available with WatchOS 2.0 or something?

The following code:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
```

results in the error:

```
Unknown type name 'NSTextAttachment'; did you mean 'NSTextAlignment'?
Use of undeclared identifier 'NSTextAttachment'
```

Everything else like NSAttributedString, etc. works.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is not a bug. Actually, WatchOS does not support NSTextAttachment, and the bad news is, there is no proper alternate solution to this problem.